# Java Bubble sort on randomised ListArray

Tags: java, arraylist, bubble-sort

I'm practising Java and can get a bubble sort working on an int[] array. I was seeing if I could make a more difficult example for myself so I made a random length ArrayList with random numbers in each element.

The problem is when bubble sort is done sometimes nothing is printed after bubbleSort2 is called. And for some reason I can't use a foreach-loop in the bubbleSort2 method.

Also let me know if my use of List and ArrayList is fine.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BubbleSort
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Integer> myList2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int min = 2;
        int max = 30;
        for (int i=0; i<(int)(Math.random() * ( max - min) + min); i++)
        {
            myList2.add((int)(Math.random() * 100));
        }

        System.out.println("Unsorted list 2");
        for (int element: myList2)
        {
            System.out.print(element + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Bubble sorted list 2 (BubbleSort2)");
        bubbleSort2(myList2);
        for(int element: myList2)
        {
            System.out.print(element + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void swap2(List<Integer> x, int i, int j)
    {
        Integer temp = x.get(i);
        x.set(i, x.get(j));
        x.set(j, temp);
    }

    public static void bubbleSort2(List<Integer> x)
    {
        int mostRightSwap = x.size() - 1;
        while (mostRightSwap > 0)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<x.size()-1; i++)
            {
                if (x.get(i) > x.get(i + 1))
                {
                    swap2(x, i, i + 1);
                    mostRightSwap = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Update:

I have figured out my problem. As pointed out here and by friends elsewhere I sometimes fall into an infinite loop when the if condition is never met. So a line of code `mostRightSwap = 0`; is added to falsify the while condition before the if statement just in case the if statement doesn't execute.

```
public static void bubbleSort(List<Integer> x)
    {
        int mostRightSwap = x.size() - 1;
        while (mostRightSwap > 0)
        {
            int right = mostRightSwap;
            mostRightSwap = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<right; i++)
            {
                if (x.get(i) > x.get(i+1))
                {
                    swap2(x, i, i+1);
                    mostRightSwap = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: with ```for (int i=0; i<(int)(Math.random() * ( max - min) + min); i++)``` it takes a new random value _every iteration_. You need to store the random in a variable and then compare ```i``` against that.

Comment: "I can't use a foreach-loop in the bubbleSort2 method" Why not?

Comment: To really challenge yourself you should make it Generic after you fix your current problems of course- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: @glglgl I think you cannot or should not use a foreach for sorting because the array is being changed on every loop, and you do not want the program to go through the entire array each pass. Each pass should become shorter as the array becomes more sorted.

Comment: @NathanWhite I'll check it out b0ss.

Comment: @JornVernee Cool, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is basicly that you are running into an infinite loop.
Your stopping condition is, if the most right swapped element is not the first element, try to bubblesort the array. But now imagine a scenario like this, with the following elements.

`[1, 5, 31, 17, 20]`. What do you think will happen? The first element will never be swapped, and you are stuck in an infinite loop since your outer while loop condition will never make the loop stop because the first element is the lowest one. I´d rather suggest a simple boolean that does check if something has been swaped for the outer while loop.

```
public static void bubbleSort2(List<Integer> x)
{
    boolean swapped = false;
    do
    {
        swapped = false;
        for (int i=0; i<x.size()-1; i++)
        {
            if (x.get(i) > x.get(i + 1))
            {
                swap2(x, i, i + 1);
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while(swapped);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using a list why not simply use predefined method over `Collections` to sort the data.

```
List<Integer> x = new ArrayList();
Collections.sort(x);
Collections.reverse(x);
```

Comment: I am practising the method of bubble sort. I'm avoiding shortcuts like that specifically.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note here.

Firstly, if you are using Java 8 you can create your random list more easily with:

```
Random rand = new Random();
List<Integer> list = rand.ints(rand.nextInt(30) + 2, 1, 100)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Secondly, `Collections` has a `swap` method.

Thirdly, I can't see how your bubble sort is supposed to end. For example, if you pass a list that is already sorted then `mostRightSwap` will remain set to the size - 1 and the loop will not exit.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That is an interesting way of constructing a random array.
Shortcuts like the `swap` method from `Collections` is some thing I wanted to avoid in this practise so I can learn the fundamentals myself.